# Need SEO Guidance on Huge dynamic website

Tags: seo, dynamic

First of all I am a programmer and have really basic knowledge like keywords, titles and content makes difference on SEO ranking. I have a website which is more like yellow pages. I have imported about 40,000 businesses and they have a SEO friendly urls as well they are divided by categories and subcategories.

If I expose all those to google at the same time will they create any problems should I open them to Google in few hundered and with couple of days between them? As this is a  large number of pages can Google end up thinking it is a spam website and hence punish it in ranking?

Also my category and paging urls are with query strings ie. ?page=1&cat=12. Can Google crawl those kind of urls? Do I have to change them to /12/1 type urls with Url rewiting?

Comment: A Google search will quickly reveal that Google *does* index URL's with GET parameters - can we edit this question down to concern only the problem of making lots of content available at once (and whether or not that impacts search rankings) ..?

Answer (score 2):

Large websites are launched everyday. The number of pages appearing at once isn't the issue, as crawl depth is a factor of page-rank. Its a sudden number of back-links that can raise a red-flag (less so now in today's link-bait webscape).

So, answer no.1: No issue with publishing 40,000 URLs. I'd be wary of how "thin" that content is though - yellow pages type sites (aka directories) don't tend to farewell in today's Googleland. I'd consider submitting an XML sitemap with Google Webmaster Tools to get an indication of crawl/indexation on all of those new URLs.

In terms of the URL parameters, Google has no issue with those, as long as you keep the number of key/value pairs to a minimum, stick to a strict order (or canonicalize where you can).

Answer (score 0):

> If I expose all those to google at the same time will they create any problems should I open them to Google in few hundered and with couple of days between them?

Not really an SEO question but rather one of "Is your hardware up to the load of Google indexing all those dynamic pages?" without causing it to fall on its face.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with exposing them all is that google won't index part of them. If you have time, it is best practice to put new content on daily basis, if your content has been indexed by google, then put another part of pages, until you put all your pages in your site, moreover most of them are indexed.

It was for the stone age that google couldn't crawl it. now there is no problem with query strings in your URL, but now the problem is ranking. If you can you should use keyword rich links.

like:   stack-exhange: .../question/1222/need-seo-guidance...

in the above example google will know that this is a question, and question is about seo.

Answer (score 0):

Please work on to create seo friendly url's with meaningful names even if it takes one month more unless you can redirect them all to new meaningful ones later.

Google will keep your old url's for a long time.

There is no problem when you launch site of any size. It could take months for Google to index them all though.

Answer (score 0):

No, there will not be any problem in launching all your pages at one go, infact its a good practice to launch all. you will start seeing traffic coming to your website. also spend some time in doing link building only onpage seo wont help.